# Laravel 5 Error 403 forbidden access webhosting

Tags: php, apache, laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wanted to deploy my Laravel 5 App on the webhost one.com

I followed along some tutorials on the internet and moved my puplic folders content into the root folder of the host and made the required path changes to the index.php file. 
But now I've got the

```
403 Error: You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I believe it's because of my **.htaccess** file:

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex public/index.php

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I'm new to **.htaccess** files and maybe you guys can help me! :)

Answer (score 1):

The 403 forbidden status you have, can be triggered by many things. I hope you get started by checking the following:

Create (or access) an existing file with your document root. Is this file accessible? If accessible, something in your .htaccess is off. If not accessible, probably not access is granted (yet), please add to your .htaccess:

```
Require all granted
```

When the test file is still not accessible, this could be a side effect of the 'Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder', please change this to:

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Another addition to your .htaccess could also solve the issue:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Let me know if (or not) your issue is resolved.

Comment: It didn't work, maybe I made another mistake deploying my laravel app. I tried to do it without SSH access, but most tutorials use SSH to setup their project. :/